# Div Background Color not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a javascript function to change the background color to a random color every few seconds but it's not working. It changes the color on the click but not changing every few seconds. I want the background to change every few seconds. I'm testing it on one div with an onclick event. I don't want to use jQuery either. Thanks for your help!

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div" onclick="timeChange()"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <script src="myScript.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**myScript.js**

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
return color;
}

function changeDivColor() {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var color = getRandomColor();
    div.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function timeChange() {
    window.setInterval(changeDivColor(), 2000);
}
```

**main.css**

```
div {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: black;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;

}
```

Comment: getElementByID() selects elements by their ID not by tag

Comment: 1. You don't have a div with the id 'div_id' (in function changeDivColor())
2. What are all the other set of divs doing in your example?

Comment: Thanks, edited the post, still does not work on a time based event. Only changes color after a click. Not after 2 seconds. Other divs are doing nothing, I'm only testing on one div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function changeDivColor() {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var color = getRandomColor();
    div.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function timeChange() {
    window.setInterval(changeDivColor, 2000);
}
```

```css
div {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" onclick="timeChange()"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) takes a function:

`window.setInterval(changeDivColor, 2000);` vs `window.setInterval(changeDivColor(), 2000);`

Comment: Thank you! This worked, stupid syntax mistake on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Create the interval on `window.onload`. I assigned the `interval` it changed to a `variable`, you can later use this to clear the interval if you wanted.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var intervalChange = setInterval(changeDivColor, 2000);
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
return color;
}

function changeDivColor() {
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    var color = getRandomColor();
    div.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/47/)**.

There's no `div_id` in your code :

```
var div = document.getElementById('div_id');
```

Should be :

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
```

Or you could change the is on tag `<div id="div" onclick="timeChange()"></div>`.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that error, but the behavior is still the same. Only changes on click, not after.